# Sending a File using Socket PHP

Tags: php, tcp

I have developed a server to listen in a TCP port .. and i need to send a file or a data to the server using PHP .. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php